# Toggle Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 checkboxes and I wish to toggle them (checked or unchecked) and they should all be the same what ever state they are in. I have this so far:

```
var toggle_click = false;

function check_them(element){

    if(toggle_click){
        $('#'+element+'_1').attr('checked', true);
        $('#'+element+'_2').attr('checked', true);
        $('#'+element+'_3').attr('checked', true);
        $('#'+element+'_4').attr('checked', true);
    }

    if(!toggle_click){
        $('#'+element+'_1').attr('checked', false);
        $('#'+element+'_2').attr('checked', false);
        $('#'+element+'_3').attr('checked', false);
        $('#'+element+'_4').attr('checked', false);
    }

    if(!toggle_click){ toggle_click = true;   }
    if(toggle_click) { toggle_click = false;  }
}
```

On page load some of the checkboxes may be ticked or not ticked - but once I click a link and run this function, I want these checkboxes to go all to the same state.

When I try the above, it just doesn't seem to tick the boxes and sometimes it ticks them all and running this function again does nothing. What is going on? I am coffee deprived and confused!

Should be making use of a checkbox group or something?

Thanks all for any help

Comment: On the last two rows, if _toggle_click_ is _false_, set it to _true_, then if it's _true_, set it to _false_. No matter what its initial value is, it will always be _false_ in the end. I'd replace those with `toggle_click = !toggle_click;`… and use one for-loop for the whole thing where the value of _toggle_click_ goes after 'checked'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

........

```
var isChecked = false;

function check_them(element){

    if(isChecked === false) {
        $('#'+element+'_1').attr('checked', true);
        $('#'+element+'_2').attr('checked', true);
        $('#'+element+'_3').attr('checked', true);
        $('#'+element+'_4').attr('checked', true);
        isChecked = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $('#'+element+'_1').attr('checked', false);
        $('#'+element+'_2').attr('checked', false);
        $('#'+element+'_3').attr('checked', false);
        $('#'+element+'_4').attr('checked', false);
        isChecked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh dear - what happened to me. If and bloody else should be used! Thanks Sarfraz!

Comment: This is unnecessarily verbose

Comment: @Justin Johnson: yes it is but i just did and fixed what he was doing, of course it can be shortened :)

Answer (score 8):

Checked is a "funny" attribute. One thing I'd suggest is rather than `attr('checked', false)`, try `removeAttr('checked')` instead.

Basically, in the DOM, the rendered element will have checked as an attribute, or if it's being XHTML compliant, `checked=checked`. So, setting it to false isn't the right thing to do.

As far as the other issues, I'm not enough of a jQuery pro yet to know.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('tr').click(function(){
        var chkbox = document.getElementById("chk"+this.id);
        chkbox.checked = !chkbox.checked;

    });
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer ? It looks good, but I don't see why you use `tr`

Answer (score 2):

It can also be done using only javascript without troubles, you can use an image or anything that lets you click it too.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <a href=" javascript:check();"> Toggle </a> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c1" > Un/Check me <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c2" > Un/Check me
  </body>
</html>

<script>
function check()
{
  c1.checked = !c1.checked;
  c2.checked = !c2.checked;
}
</script>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for different approach:  Sets checkboxs all to whatever it wasn't:

```
var toggle_click = false;
function setCheck(mythis)
{
    $('#'+element+'_1').checked = !mythis.checked;
    $('#'+element+'_2').checked = !mythis.checked;
    $('#'+element+'_3').checked = !mythis.checked;
    $('#'+element+'_4').checked = !mythis.checked;
    toggle_click = !toggle_click;
};
$(function() { 
  $('#'+element+'_1').click(function() {
    setCheck(this);
  });
  $('#'+element+'_2').click(function() {
     setCheck(this);
  });
  $('#'+element+'_3').click(function() {
    setCheck(this);
  });
  $('#'+element+'_4').click(function() {
      setCheck(this);
  });
});
```

NOTE IF you give them a class called "mycheckbox" even simpler:

```
var toggle_click = false;
$(function() { 
  $('.mycheckbox').click(function() {
    $('.mycheckbox').each().checked = !this.checked;
    toggle_click = !toggle_click;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the attribute checked to false, just remove it altogether! :)

$('#'+element+'_1').removeAttr('checked');

Here's an example:

```
var state = $("#element1").attr("checked") === "checked" ? true : false;
$("#test").click(function(){    
    $("input[id^=element]").each(function(){
        if(state === false){
            $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
        }else{
            $(this).removeAttr("checked");
        }
    });
    state = !state;        
});
```

Comment: `$("#element1").attr("checked") === "checked"` Isn't boolean enough for you? ` ? true : false` can be dropped altogether.

Comment: If you read the rest of the code you would see that since the property is removed the attribute is either TRUE or UNDEFINED.
Thanks for the bogus -1.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't call `check_them` before the DOM is finished loading

```
$(function() {
    check_them("whatever");
});
```

Also, you can simplify this whole thing to the following:

```
var check_them = (function() {
    var is_checked = false; // Now this is not global, huzzah
    return function(element) {
        // You can update all of the elements at once
        $('#'+element+'_1, #'+element+'_2, #'+element+'_3, #'+element+'_4').attr('checked', !is_checked);
        is_checked = !is_checked;
    };
})();
```